# Configure email notification with redmine

Tags: email, redmine

I have configured the email notification in redmine and put all the information in config/configuration.yml, but I am still unable to get the email notification from redmine.

Please guide me through the right process of it, how can I configure the email notification in redmine. I am using the Google apps for email and my domain is 3roosters.com

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed, as it does 'relate to programming or software development in some way'. What is the more appropriate forum that the question should be asked in?

Comment: See your logs. May be redmine sends all, but next step is broken -- your local postfix or sendmail.